# how to extract minutes and seconds from PT Format datetime using re in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How do I extract minute and second from the time formats `PT34M23S` or `PT32S` and convert them into total seconds?

```py
import re
M= re.compile('[\d]+M')
S= re.compile('[\d]+S')

txt='PT32S'
m=re.compile('[\d]+')
s=re.compile('[\d]+')
if M.findall(txt)!=[]:
    mins=M.findall(txt)
    secs=S.findall(txt)
    mm=m.findall(mins[0])
    ss=s.findall(secs[0])
else:
    ss=s.finall(S.findall(txt)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options for extracting the seconds from these date formats.

Using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

txt = "PT34M23S"
seconds = 0

try:
    seconds += int(re.search(r"(\d+)S$", txt).group(1))
    seconds += int(re.search(r"(\d+)M", txt).group(1)) * 60
except AttributeError:
    pass

print(seconds) # => 2063
```

Using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library:

```
from datetime import datetime

txt = "PT34M23S"
dt = 0

try:
    dt = datetime.strptime(txt, "PT%MM%SS") 
except ValueError:
    dt = datetime.strptime(txt, "PT%SS") 

seconds = (dt - datetime.strptime("0", "%S")).total_seconds()
print(seconds) # => 2063.0
```